# Java Как получить файлы из архива rar (v.4)? (Apache Tika)

Tags: java, apache

Я хочу обработать файл file.rar, в котором содержаться 2 файла. Это 1.txt и 2.txt.

Текст из файла 1.txt:

```
word1 word1
```

Текст из файла 2.txt:

```
word2 word2
```

После обработки архива этим кодом:

```
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(newStr))){
                
                String mimeType = tika.detect(is);
                metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);
                
                AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                ParseContext pc = new ParseContext(); 
                ContentHandler ch = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
                parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc);

                byte[] arrayCh = ch.toString().trim().getBytes("UTF-8");
                
                file_size = arrayCh.length;
                if(arrayCh.length != 0){ 
                
                    String outdir = Path[1];

                    String newName = outdir + File.separator + datFile.replace("dat", "txt");
                    File outPutFile_json = new File(newName);
                    outPutFile_json.createNewFile();
                 }

                 System.out.println("ch: "+ch.toString());

             catch(){
               .... 
             }
```

После строчки:

```
parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc);
```

В переменной:

```
ch.toString()
```

Храниться такое содержимое:

```
word1 word1 2.txtword2 word2
```

То есть Tika достала содержимое архива и сохранила это в одно место, а именно в переменную ch.

---

Подскажите как достать содержимое так, чтобы оно было в разных переменных, например текст из первого файла в одном месте, текст из второго файла в другом, чтобы было не так, что все в одной переменной ch.toString(), а две новые переменные или что-то типа массива, который имеет размер кол-во вложенных файлов, и чтобы содержимое хранилось не в одной переменной.

Подскажите как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Наверное придётся вместо использования `org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler`  реализовать свой `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler` Ждать появления элемента вида  `<div class="package-entry"><h1>1.txt</h1>...</div>` Здесь точки - это искомая строка, которую надо сохранить в нужную переменную. Именно в виде документа с такими элементами поступают архивы в `org.xml.sax.ContentHandler`. Примитивная реализация этого интерфейса `org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler` тупо склеивает весь обнаруженный текст вместе.

Comment: Можно запустить `unrar.exe` с помощью `ProcessBuilder`. Извлечь таким образом архив в определённую папку и читать файлы штатными средствами `FileInputStream` например